# The limitations of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql

Ok, Im working on a web app with MongoDB as Database. Working with Mongodb have been pretty easy, but now I have encountered a limit that gets me into trouble.

In a collection I'm saving events. Among other fields, these events have a start and an end, saved as `Dates` in Mongodb.

```
events { 
  start: "Date1",
  end: "Date2",
  ...
}
```

When inserting new documents in this collection I need a constrain that forbids insertion of document which start-end dates overlapping an event alreay created. In short, I dont want any events share the same time span.

To make a long story short this is as good as impossible to do in MongoDB, and instead I'm finding myself compromise the design of my data structure around the limitations of the DB. The compromise is to split the time range in discrete 15 minutes steps and put these into an array which is given a unique index.

I think all Databases have it's share of ups and downs, but I would like to hear from you who knows postgressql if this would be a problem there aswell?

Comment: Such a constraint is _very_ easy to implement in Postgres using range types and exclusion constraints: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75036/1822  Plus Postgres is faster :) http://blogs.enterprisedb.com/2014/09/24/postgres-outperforms-mongodb-and-ushers-in-new-developer-reality/

Comment: The philosophy here is: do you want to have business logic in the database? I sure as hell don't, and I'd prefer a few sanity checks in code and an asynchronous worker over business logic that is in my database and depends on the state of the database, some initialization scripts, deployment processes and database administrators. But I guess we each can and have to choose our own poison here...

Comment: @mnemosyn: any constraint that can statically be defined should got into the database. Because usually the database (and its data) lives much longer that the application(s) and any database that contains interesting information _will_ be accessed by more than one application (or system). And finally: why re-invent the wheel? The people developing a DBMS have put much more time and effort into developing that than I could ever do and it's e.g. impossible to get FK checking right in the application layer(s).

Comment: I doubt that this is the way to approach a discussion that goes on since the 70s, but to repeat two key arguments: why would you ever allow more than one tool to access the database? Service oriented architectures don't need this: some constraints are too complex for the database to understand in any case, which leaves us with two 'classes' of constraints, a largely random separation of constraints where part is in the code, part in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this with a (somewhat awkward) trick using unique indexes on arrays by representing the  time period as an array of time slices, which I think is what you alluded to in the question. You can also enforce this restraint pretty easily on the client side using [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) and [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/):

```
db.events.findAndModify({
    "query" : { "start" : {"$lte" : end_time }, "end" : { "$gte" : start_time } },
    "update" : { // setOnInsert operators }
    "upsert" : true
})
```

If you have a unique id of some sort on the documents, you can tell if there was overlap by checking the unique id of the return of findAndModify against the id of the new doc you were trying to insert. You can also do a find and then conditionally an insert if atomicity of the check+insert isn't needed.

---

To respond to your first comment, the findAndModify approach would not work for atomic changes. You can change the time frame either by dealing with two documents - old and new - or altering the time in the old document. The first approach can't be atomic since it affects more than one document and atomicity is generally only guaranteed at the per-document level in MongoDB. The second approach can't easily respect the non-overlapping constraint, since an update can't be relative to another document and there isn't a way to use a unique index for overlaps except to have overlaps on values (that awkward trick I booked up before). I would never describe it as elegant, but I think the array of time slices is actually very feasible for a lot of use cases involving things like reservations because all time periods are multiples of a smallest time period, usually 15 or 30 minutes. Managing the overlaps in application code is also perfectly doable (and how I would go about it).

To respond to the second, the various features that are requested, being worked on, and scheduled for release are tracked in a [public JIRA project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER) so you should dig around there to see if you can find what you're after. I don't think there's any kind of feature for implementing some kind of index to prevent overlaps. It's not a common need and can be handled in application code. You can always submit a feature request and see if it gets traction with the engineers but I think they'll say it's application-specific enough it's best handled on the application side using tools already available in MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. I had another question up earlier where I asked for a solution to this. You pointed me in the "time period as an array of time slice" - solution. 

But it's like you say. It feels awkward, and limited. Lets say i want my time split in small slices, like five minutes. This would require an array of 23 time elements... and that seems like a lot of extra saved data for just wanting to ensure uniqueness on a time span.

Comment: Regarding the other solution using findAndModify and $setOnInsert. This will work fine when creating new events. But if I would like to atomically CHANGE the time of a created event and still honour the non-overlapping constraint this usage of findAndModify will not work. Feel free to prove me wrong with some code =)

Comment: Btw, your description says you work for MongoDB, Inc. Do you possibly know about new feature in upcoming versions of MongoDB that will make this particular problem go away?

Comment: Responses added to the answer.

Comment: I dont find your response :)